# Accurate per-database cost

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand there's a `METERING_DAILY_HISTORY` table that gives the costs per day, and `METERING_HISTORY` per hour. But those are aggregate, I'd like to break down those costs by database.

The approach I'm taking is to query [`QUERY_HISTORY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html), group by database, and for the cost I take EXECUTION_TIME * (the cost of the warehouse as determined from WAREHOUSE_SIZE) * QUERY_LOAD_PERCENT/100.

However I'm getting an overestimate. I can tell because when I sum my number for every database, I get a number that is higher than what METERING_DAILY_HISTORY reports. If this method were accurate I'd expect the two to match.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better (yet still reasonably simple) way to estimate these costs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bunch of stuff at issue here.

1. databases have nothing to do with compute costs.
2. you are attributing the query to the current context of the database, which may not have anything to do with the query itself.  In other words, a user could login, set their context to a database, but then query a completely different database by simply referencing using fully qualified object names.
3. assuming you don't care about #1 or #2, you are using the `query_load_percent` to attribute some fraction of the cost of the warehouse to that query.  That's not really the best way to do it, because that number doesn't mean that 100% of the resources are being used by something at all times.  You should instead try and determine the number of queries being executed during that timeframe (complicated SQL) to assign a % of that time to that query.
4. warehouses can be running while no queries are being executed, so that cost isn't being attributed to anything.

In the end, getting your real costs correctly attributed to a database (or a user/role, which I've seen seen requested before, as well) isn't going to be an exact number.  There are probably better ways to simply get something approximate, but `query_load_percent` isn't the factor you'd want to use.